# Working on my first CSS grid. Have an issue with grid positioning and objects overlapping

Tags: html, css

Title explains most of it. I want a 3x2 grid covering the bottom 40% of the page. I cannot seem to move the div and the objects overlap.

https://jsfiddle.net/draymon/r7538o2x/3/#&togetherjs=ymVMBJNyuV

```
    body,
    html {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }

    div {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
    }
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        height: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
        position: relative;
    }
    .grid-item {
        border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        position: relative;
    }
    .content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 35%;
    }
```

Comment: you should add grid-template-rows: 400px 300px;

Comment: Now it has a gap between rows. Using grid-row-gap: 0px; i could not get rid of this. How could I get rid of the gap? I am trying to make it so it sizes to each row being 20% of the bottom of the screen

Comment: you can try this   display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 300px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;

Comment: you should add grid-gap: 10px

Comment: well ading the CSS you provided fixed the overlap problem, but now I can't move the div to the bottom of the page.

Comment: can  u share code or url. i will check and let you know

Comment: It is the JsFiddle link in the original post. https://jsfiddle.net/draymon/r7538o2x/3/#&togetherjs=ymVMBJNyuV

Comment: you asked position of bottom ?

Comment: Yes. Whenever I get it down it overlaps. I have not been able to get both together

Comment: you should add height in 100px instead 40%

Comment: That works in moving it, but I am trying to make it so it resizes to the clients screens.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend that you have a look at flexbox, I find it way easier and simpler to use. You can read more on it here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Trust me, its a lot easier than css grid's

Hope this sorts out your problem <3